# Properties of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If $A = \left\{x: x \in \mathbb{R}, |x^2-3|<1\right\}$ and $B = \left\{x^2: x \in \mathbb{R}, |x-3|<1\right\}$ then which of these is true?
>
> $\mathbf{(A)} ~ A \subset B$,  $\mathbf{(B)} ~ B \subset A$, $\mathbf{(C)} ~ A \cap B = \emptyset,$ $\mathbf{(D)} ~ A\setminus B = \emptyset$ and $\mathbf{(E)}$ None of these

I thought should rewrite $B$ as $B = \left\{x: x \in \mathbb{R}, |\pm \sqrt{x}-3|<1\right\}$ but it didn't get me anywhere.

I can't check any of the properties because I can't get $B$ to a form where I can compare it with $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let wrrite $A = \{ \sqrt{2} < x < 2 \} \cup \{ -2 < x < -\sqrt{2}\}$ and $B = \{4 < x < 16\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=\{x:x∈R,|x^2−3|<1\}$
$$  -1<x^2−3<1  $$
$$  3-1<x^2<1+3  $$
$$  2<x^2<4  $$
$$  (-2<x<-\sqrt2)\cup(\sqrt2<x<2)  $$
$$ x \in (-2,-\sqrt2)\cup (\sqrt2,2) $$
If $B=\{x^2:x∈R,|x−3|<1\}$
$$ -1< x−3<1 $$
$$ 3-1< x<1+3 $$

$$ 2<x<4 $$

$$ x\in(2,4) $$
$$ A \cap B=x \in   \{(-2,-\sqrt2)\cup(\sqrt2,2)\} \cap (2,4)= \phi $$

Comment: In case set $A$, third line cannot go to the fourth.

Comment: The set $A$ given is incomplete. $-2<x<-\sqrt{2}$ is missing.